# Associate a particular type of projects with a specific perspective

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I want to associate all Java projects with **only** the Java perspective. However, at this time, the java projects also show up in the Ruby perspective under the Ruby explorer. I want only ruby projects to show up in the ruby perspective. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't, there's zero relationship between the two apart from anything the new project wizard might do for you.  Check the Ruby Explorer's local menu for a way to filter the projects you don't want to see in there.